# question about Herbert B. Enderton's book : A mathematical introduction to logic

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, first-order-logic

I hope someone can help me. My question arises on page 114 of the second edition of the book. Here the notion of 'prime formula' is introduced to enable one to view a formula as a formula of sentential logic and as a formula of first order logic at the same time. One way to do this is to let the prime formulas be the sentential symbols. So far so good - now to my question:
In order to guarantee unique readability of strings of symbols it is demanded in the book that the symbols of sentential logic (including of course the sentential symbols) be such that no symbol is a finite string of other symbols. This is explained in detail on page 14. Now if I choose prime formulas a my 'new' sentential symbols I have no idea how to show that this holds for the 'new' set of symbols containing:

Negation symbol, implication symbol, brackets and prime formulas (which themselves are strings of symbols potentially containing for example the negation symbol)

The problem arises mainly because tuples are treated in a set-theoretic way (as sets) in the book as explained in the preliminary chapter 0 on page five.

I hope I managed to make clear what exactly the question is - I did my best to do so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is not a real issue.

A formula of *first-order* logic is **not** made of propositional symbols.

The correct syntactical rules are "managed" in page 105-on, with a "new" proof of the **UNIQUE READABILITY THEOREMs** for *terms* and *formulae*.

Is only in showing that we can "reuse" the tautologies as *valid* f-o formulae (and thus as axioms) [see page 114] :

> *Axiom group 1* consists of generalizations of formulas to be called tautologies. These are the wffs obtainable from tautologies of sentential logic (having only the connectives $¬$ and $→$) by replacing each sentence symbol by a wff of the first-order language.

that we use the "subterfuge" of :

> [taking] the sentence symbols to be the prime formulas of our first-order language. Then any tautology of sentential logic (that uses only the connectives $¬,→$) is in axiom group 1. There is no need to replace sentence symbols here by first-order wffs; they already are first-order wffs.

---

*Added*

My understanding is this :

*(i)* Review the sintax of **First-Order Languages** (page 69) and compare with **The Language of Sentential Logic** (page 13).

The following :

> $(A_1 \rightarrow A_1)$ --- (A)

is a *well-formed formula* of sentential logic but **not** of first-order logic.

And it is a *tautology*.

*(ii)* The following :

> $(A_1^1v_1 \rightarrow A_1^1v_1)$

is a *well-formed formula* of first-order logic (specifically, of *Pure predicate language* (see page 70).

According to the definition of *logical axiom* (page 112), the following

> $\forall v_1(A_1^1v_1 \rightarrow A_1^1v_1)$ --- (B)

in an instance of a logical axiom group 1, i.e. the generalization of a (first-order) instance of a tautology, because - accdording to the explanation on page 114 :

> Axiom group 1 consists of generalizations of formulas to be called *tautologies*. These are the wffs obtainable from tautologies of sentential logic (having only the connectives $¬$ and $→$) by replacing each sentence symbol by a wff of the first-order language.

Formula (B) is the generalization of the formula obtainable from (A) by replacing the sentence symbol $A_1$ by a the wff of the first-order language $A_1^1v_1$, which is an *atomic* formula, and so a *prime* one.

*(iii)* I think that Enderton's note (page 114) is an euristic suggestion; instad of starting from a tautology and find the suitable substitution which gives us the "corresponding" f-o formula, we can start directly from the f-o formula "reading it" as a sentential one, where in place of sentential letters we have *prime* formulas. In this way we can take benefit of the truth-table device to check if the f-o formula is an instance of an axiom group 1.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly. Will come back to it tomorrow and take my time. Maybe I took the subject for  object in the sentence "...but take the sentence symbols to be the prime formulas of or first-order language."

Comment: Thank you very much for your extensive answer (I'm Florian Piringer (pi o r))! I'm afraid I still don't understand completely. Here's what I understand: I understand that any f-o wff can be built up from prime formula using the not-operator and the -> operator. If I am given a number of "boxes", each containing a symbol of f-o logic (these symbols have by assumption the property that no such symbol is a finite sequence of other such symbols), I can scan the formula from left to right and do the following. If I have before me one of the symbols (, ), -> or "not" I write this symbol down and "pu

Comment: You should get your accounts merged; use [this support form](http://math.stackexchange.com/contact) to request the merge. Then you'll be able to comment on the answers posted to your question. This post is obviously not an answer.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: @900 sit-ups a day: I tried to merge my comments and filled out the support form. I was informed that I was to get an e-Mail soon, which until now hasn't arrived. That's why I undeleted the message, since unfortunately I have no idea how to answer to Mauro ALLEGRANZA any other way without opening a new question (as pi o r).

Comment: We have different things in place. Th def of $n$-tuple [page 4] and the relevant **LEMMA 0A**. The definition of *expression* as a finite sequence of symbols [page 15] and the use of the previous Lemma to assure that finite sequences of symbols are uniquely decomposable. The formation-tree for formulae [page 17] which give us a unique decomposition. The same mechanism is applied to first-order formulae in *polish notation* [i.e., insted of $\lnot (p \rightarrow q)$ we have $\lnot \rightarrow pq$].

Comment: For this application, there are no *prime* formulae; only *atomic* ones and "complex" ones : see page 108. As I said above, the devide of prime formulae is intended only as an aid for "recognizing" tautologies in f-o logic. If you do not "like" it, stay with the official def of instance of a prop tautology. In this case you check that its "sentential form" is well-formed according to the rules for prop logic, and **after** you replace every sent letter with a f-o formula, the same formula for all occurrences of the same sent letter.

Comment: It's a pity, 'cause I would have found the use of prime formulae as propositional symbols so elegant. But you're right, I might as well choose the alternative point of view without loosing anything. Thank ypu very much for your help!